# Visual Studio 2012 Custom Solution Explorer Filter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, filtering, visual-studio-sdk, solution-explorer

We have a very large solution project for our MVC structure where I work.  I am trying to filter my solution explorer down to only relevant files with a custom filter.  Microsoft has an article on making a custom filter [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh966591.aspx), but when I try to build the source code they give it says one of the .NET Framework namespaces is not available (I have already reinstalled .NET).  The namespace that won't resolve is: System.ComponentModel.Composition.  I am hoping fixing this will allow me correctly build a filter (there are 5 errors in the project total).

I definitely have the 2012 SDK installed (you won't make it far in the tutorial without it).

Answer (score 0):

The [Funnel extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5396fa4a-d638-471b-ac3d-671ccd2ea369) may be what you're looking for:

> Decrease solution loading and re-compilation times dramatically by filtering projects not relevant for the current task.

The extension loads just the projects defined in filters (load filters must be defined before using them).

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's considered good practice to paste main information in linked pages so it'll always available. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've to add reference to "*System.ComponentModel.Composition*" assembly. This reference is in framework 4.0.

If you've problem referencing or finding this assembly, refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310236/2617201